# (.NET Core 3.1+) Need to use/call an API username and password to access API methods. Best and most secure way to call/store this data?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

So long story short, I need to pass in a username and password to a web API in order to receive a JWT giving me access to use the API. I'll need to call the API for both web and console apps, so it will be used a lot.

I obviously don't want to call it using plaintext in the app(s) (them)selves because I don't want the credentials stored in version control. I also don't want to use Secret Manager or Environment Variables, because these apps will be used in production.

The only thing I can think of is storing the username/password (as plaintext) somewhere on the server and letting Windows Authentication handle the security of the data.

Is that a good practice though? I mean I guess it's as secure as the server is and if someone got access into the server we'd have bigger problems, but it just seems like it isn't good practice.

Also, I know Azure Key Vault would be ideal in this scenario, but the company is going through a lot of transitions and finances are up in the air with covid - so we're trying to minimize costs as much as possible for the time being.

Any one have any input?

Comment: Hi Daath - can you please let us know how will you host your application ? Will it be hosted in azure cloud (Azure app service ) ?

Comment: Hey @AdityaSingh - we use IIS to host all of our applications

Comment: Hi Daath - if the application is hosted on IIS on premises then I would recommend that the user name and password should be stored in database and whenever the credentials are required to gain an access token the credentials can be fetched from db to request an acces token .This will make the management of credentials easy.

Comment: Since you're talking about environment vars, etc...is this a single set of credentials for all access, or do you have a list of users?  And Key Vault is a fairly low cost service at US$0.03 per 10K transactions.

Comment: @BryanLewis I completely agree that Key Vault is low cost, but unfortunately bureaucracy rules over here, so it would have to go up the chain and that can take a while especially right now. But I do 100% want to get it implemented in the (hopefully) near future. So I guess this is more of a temporary solution, but I do want to make it as secure as possible. And as for the credentials - it's only a single set. Appreciate the response!

Comment: @AdityaSingh The thought of storing it in a db did cross my mind, but I didn't even think of using an access token, that might solve my problems. Thank you very much!